# button click event non responsive

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery form validation plugin and I need to display an error when a user clicks a submit button while the form is empty. However, my click event is not responsive.

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
     <head>
        <link type = "text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
           <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jzaefferer.github.com/jquery-           validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
           <script src="js/bootstrap.js"> </script>

           <script> 
                 $('#submit').click(function(){ 
                                 $('form').validate()
                             }); 

        </script> 
     </head>
     <body> 
     <form class = "well span6"> 

     <label> Username </label> 
     <input type="text" id = "myName" class ="span3" placeholder ="Type your username     here..." class = "required"/> 

      <label> Password</label> 
     <input type="text" id "myPassword" class ="span3" placeholder ="Type your password here..." class = "required"/> <br/> 

     <button id = "submit" class ="btn btn-primary">Submit </button>
     <button class = "" > Clear <br/></button><br/> 
     </form> 



     </body> 

    </html>
```

Any help will be appreciated and rewarded.

Comment: I rolled back to the original question.  StackOverflow is not meant for questions to continually change into something else every time one aspect is solved.  Please ask a concise question and if you need more help with something else, ask a new question.

Comment: OK, is it ok if I ask you the explanation for you javascript code in jsfiddle? Just the javascript code. I didnt understand the code at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you bind `.validate()` to a `click` or `submit` event, you are only first initializing the plugin on the first click. Since validation plugin was not ready when you first clicked the button, nothing happens or it behaves unexpectedly.

As already pointed out, you simply need to initialize the plugin on DOM ready.  The plugin already has event handlers built in that take care of validating the form automatically on various events, including the `submit` click.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').validate();
});​
```

---

You also had **two** `class` attributes on your `input` elements which was causing the `required` class to be ignored.

```
<input type="text" id="myName" class="span3" placeholder="Type your username here..." class="required" />
```

Simply combine them:

```
<input type="text" name="myName" id="myName" class="span3 required" placeholder="Type your username here..." />
```

I also added the `name` attribute to each `input` element.

Working Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZjVWd/

Comment: Excellent, works perfectly. So just curious here, @barmar was saying that replacing validate() with valid() will catch error before submit button is clicked. Is that correct?

Comment: @Stranger: no, you misunderstood him.  `.validate()` is used to initialize the form validation plugin on DOM ready.  `.valid()` can be used to test the form for validity at any time.  However, the plugin already automatically tests the form's validity whenever the form's `submit` button is clicked.

Comment: There seems to be a bug here. I am getting the error message but when I reload the page or when I load the page then the error message is displays regardless of whether you click the button or not. Why is that?

Comment: @Stranger: The jsFiddle demo is working perfectly fine.  I do not see what you describe.

Comment: @Stranger, please only _append_ your original question.  Your edit has blown out all original meaning and rendered answers useless.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21972/discussion-between-stranger-and-sparky)

Answer (score 2):

Just attach validation to the form when the document is ready, it automatically validates when the user tries to submit:

```
$(function () {
    $("form").validate();
});
```

The `validate()` function does not actually perform validation, it just initializes the plugin and attaches it to the specified form. If you want to perform on-demand validation, you can call `valid()` after having initialized it. But you don't need to do this if you just want validation done automatically during submission, that's the default behavior of the plugin.

Comment: I wish I could +1 this answer about ten more times.  It's baffling how this simple plugin is so often misunderstood... people, **no need** to bind `.validate()` to an external `click` or `submit` handler!

Comment: @Sparky, we are newbies, apologize for the frustration that this might be causing you.

Comment: @Stranger: Relax pal, I'm not frustrated with you, I'm frustrated with the people who perpetuate this misconception by posting it in their answers.

Comment: I've added some more details to my answer.

Comment: I appreciate your help. So, can you guys give me an alternative of solving this issue: Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "file:///C:/Users/Desktop/js/bootstrap.js". mimi.html:20. This is the error that I am currently getting in my console.

Comment: That script error has nothing to do with validation, it's related to `<script src="js/bootstrap.js"> </script>`. Add `type="text/javascript"` to it.

Comment: @Stranger, `Bootstrap.js` has nothing to do with `.validate()` plugin.  Please post a new question if you now have issues with something else.